# Apache Pulsar - Got exception io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds x amount - discarded

Tags: apache-pulsar

When I run a command via pulsar-admin, it works fine, but when I try to run the equivalent command via cURL or via the REST interface directly, I get:

> 2023-03-10T15:45:06,468-0700 [pulsar-io-19-8] WARN
> org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx - [/127.0.0.1:64346] Got
> exception io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame
> length exceeds 5253120: 1195725860 - discarded    at
> io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.fail(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:507)
> [long stacktrace]

Here's an example.
This works fine:

```
bin/pulsar-admin schemas get transactions
```

with this client.conf:

```
authParams=
authPlugin=
brokerServiceUrl=pulsar://localhost:6650/
tlsAllowInsecureConnection=false
tlsCertificateFilePath=
tlsEnableHostnameVerification=false
tlsKeyFilePath=
tlsKeyStorePassword=
tlsKeyStorePath=
tlsKeyStoreType=JKS
tlsTrustCertsFilePath=
tlsTrustStorePassword=
tlsTrustStorePath=
tlsTrustStoreType=JKS
useKeyStoreTls=false
webServiceUrl=http://localhost:8080/
webserviceTlsProvider=
```

However, when I run the command via cURL, I get this:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:6650...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6650 (#0)
> GET /admin/v2/schemas/public/default/transactions/schema HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6650
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
```

My standalone.conf or broker.conf file is using default configs.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the problem is that you're trying to run an admin command (which should be hitting the admin port at 8080 for non-TLS or 8443 for TLS) against the port for the Pulsar protocol, which is 6650 for non-TLS or 6651 for TLS, assuming that ports are configured to defaults on the server-side.
Make sure you're hitting the right ports.

Another potential cause in a similar situation would be mixing up TLS and non-TLS ports.